# Local imports work in bundled PyInstaller app but in Python source

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-import, python-internals

This issue has plagued me for the last few months, I need a more experienced opinion. We have a CLI Python application that uses a gRPC server to communicate with other backend services. Its structured something like this:

```
app
    - gRPC_service
        - __init__.py
        - service_related_files.py
        - service_tests
            - __init__.py
            - test_service.py
    
    - src
        - __init__.py
        - src_files.py

    - python-win
        - python37.dll

    - gRPC_service.spec
```

A few notes about the application:

- The `src` directory houses the lower level machine learning code. The `gRPC_service` directory acts as a wrapper around the `src` code and sends processed requests to a given client
- The `python-win` directory is a specific version of the Python Interpreter. Many things throughout the code base are reliant on a specific version of Python (3.7.9). This was our solution to making the code base a bit more portable. A developer can clone the repository and immediately have the necessary version of Python installed along with the plethora of 3rd party dependencies after running a `Create-VirtualEnvironment.ps1` script that uses the `python.exe` in the `python-win` directory.

The number one issue I have faced when developing this application is namespace and importing issues, and I'm not exactly sure what's causing it. We have a sub-application within the `src` directory that only imports modules from within the `src` package and uses 3rd party libraries. This works just fine with no `ModuleNotFound` errors.

Issues begin to surface when importing `src` modules from within the `gRPC_service` package. Even though both packages have `__init__.py` files, `ModuleNotFound` errors will be thrown if the PYTHONPATH is not modified at runtime. A work-around solution to this is to collect all the different file paths to each package within `app` and add them to `sys.path`. It goes without saying this is inconvenient.

This works for importing a majority of the modules, but to add to the confusion, some of the modules from the `src` package can only be imported after modifying `sys.path` AND adding a `src.` prefix to all of the local imports within the `src` package. Adding this prefix to local imports breaks the sub-application in the `src` package that I was speaking of earlier. A 'src can't be found' error gets thrown in the sub-app when doing this.

Additionally, without adding the `src.` prefixes to corresponding imports, no `ModuleNotFound` errors are thrown when the gRPC_service is bundled as a PyInstaller `.exe`. I have modified the pathex within the `.spec` file. The app works just fine when bundled - how do I get equivalent behavior when just running Python from source?

So I am looking for some advice from Python devs who have worked on large code bases. Is this issue common? What can I do to alleviate the inconvenience of modifying the PYTHONPATH at runtime? Is there a fix-all solution that tends to the needs of both applications within this codebase?

Comment: @Alexander thank you for your suggestion. The next version I release will likely be its own project and repository.

Comment: @Alexander, you could add this as an answer, I think its acceptable

Comment: Sure I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two solutions,

1. Split `gRPC_services` into its own project and repository and add it as a dependency of this project and install and import it like any other third party library.
2. move the `gRPC_services` folder inside of the `src` folder as a subpackage.